# Como saber la posición de mi arreglo

Tags: java

Me pidieron llenar un arreglo con 10 datos y quiere el profesor que el dato que esta en la posición 4 (Seria 5 porque arreglos inicia en 0) realice una suma de 5
Mas especifico así

```
//Llene mi arreglo con 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```

Mi posición *4* seria *5*, en mi arreglo ya llenado,
entonces ese *5* le tengo que sumar solo *5*

Si hubiese llenado mi arreglo como:

```
10 20 30 40 50 60 70 80 90
```

Entonces el 50 que es la posición *4* le tengo que sumar *5*

¿Cómo puedo saber la posición del arreglo?

```
    import java.util.*;
    public class Main{  
        public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner (System.in);
            int[] a= new int[10];
            for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                a[i]=sc.nextInt();
            }
            for(int k: a){
                System.out.print(k+" ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! o sea, vos queres esto? a[5] = a[5] + 5? sumarle 5 a la posicion 5 del arreglo?

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende ya para empezar. Si defines como dices el array como 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6.... El elemento 4 nunca será el que tiene el valor 5, lo digas como lo digas. Si te refieres al cuarto elemento, es el que tiene valor 3. Si te refieres al elemento con el índice 4, al empezar en 0, el índice 4 apunta al elemento con valor 4. Y ya el resto de la pregunta.... pues eso, que no se entiende.

Comment: La posición en tu bucle es la variable `i`, literalmente...

Answer (score 0):

Primero que nada, el `5` nunca se encontrara en la posicion `[4]` si ingresas al arreglo los numeros desde `0-9`, para tu primer ejemplo, tu arreglo deberia quedar algo como:

```
[ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

Puedes sumar `5` al valor que colocas en la posicion `4` inmediatamente despues de ingresarlo.

```
for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                a[i]=sc.nextInt();
                if(i==4) a[i]+=5;
            }
```

Otra opción es que al momento de imprimir el arreglo, ahí puedes sumar el `5` justo antes de imprimir el valor que se encuentra en la posicion `[4]`.

```
for (int i=0;i<a.length;i++){
                if(i==4) a[i]+=5;
                System.out.print(a[i]+" ");
            }
```

Comment: gracias, era exactamente lo que estaba buscado ya solo lo adapte a mi codigo y mi arreglo lo llene de
//1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 0
Ahora con el codigo ya es
//1 2 3 4 10 6 7 8 9 0
Era exactamente lo que buscaba muchas gracias